# Is it possible to click a link in dropdown list without selecting that option?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list. When users hover on an option, the view link will show up. You can click "View" to see more details of that option. But now every time I click it that option will have to be selected. Is there a way to make it so that when I click "View", I can see details in a popup window and that option won't be selected? Or is there a way to go around it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by making the clickable area of the view link (the `<a>` anchor tag) a container box with a higher z-index than the dropdown option

Then the view link will be on top, and clicking it will link without selecting the underlying dropdown option.